# how to protect a site-wide secret key

Tags: php, security, cryptography, passwords

1. Imagine a pretty standard website, with user authenticating with email/password pair. For passwords, it already ha shashing with random salt, but the rest of data is kept unencrypted.
2. We do another step forward and encrypt the sensitive data with a <s>password</s> key, the **key**, obviously, shall be known to the application to be able to decript the data for its operation.
3. we don't want to have it in the source code, so it's kept in a file and read by the app when it needs it.
4. we've secured the file so that only user which executes the app can read it
5. (this point has appeared after some discussions below) We have already considered buying hardware HSM and found that not possible (for instance we are running the server on a virtual machine)

this way we are relatively protected from complete DB stealing, right? However, the key might become known if someone gets access to the OS user with read rights.

**the question is: what are the best practices for keeping such key secure?**

Comment: make sure hackers dont get access to your server

Comment: Maybe better suited on [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @bish: well, yes... but isn't the whole point of security measures to protect yourself from unexpected things you didnn't foresee?

Comment: You are doing that by adding as many layers of security as deemed sensible. Access rights to files and so forth are definitely a step in the right direction. Obviously you cannot defend against "unexpected things", you can only make sure that that they are *unlikely* to happen. Note that you cannot encrypt anything with a password, you need a cryptographic key for that. Better make sure you use the correct terms to describe your protocol.

Comment: yes, thanks for correction. The key file must for sure be readable by the app. And what if the app itself is compromised? Is ther anything we can do to handle this risk? I was thinking that it might be reasonable to keep the key somewhere in the memory so that only specific process knows it. we can move encryption and decription routines to a separate process and give the key on the its startup. Even is someone gets root permissions on the server, he can't read another processes memory. For me however it looks overly complicated. what do you think? Is there anything obvoious i'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buy a hardware security module and keep the key in it. The key will not be able to be read.

Yubi makes a reasonably priced hsm. $500 if I recall correctly.

While we're here, your db server should be on a different box in a different network zone as your web server.

Comment: This is the correct solution. The application doesn't need to know the key. It only needs to be able to **use** the key for encryption and decryption.

Comment: cool, thanks, actually I came across them (yubi) some time ago, but was also wondering if we can implement anything ourselves without harwarde dongles. We'll check if they can ship to our country. as for @Borealid's comment: what exactly does it give to have DB server in a different zone? If the app is compromised, the attacker is able to access the db (as the app itself can) no matter if it's placed locally or wherever else. Right?

Comment: @user13122695 if they get root on your web server they don't automatically get root on your db. Your web server should connect to db with minimal privileges. You could consider database auth too where each user gets own db acct, though performance is affected. Use diff accts for diff needs such as login or read or write

Comment: @user1312695 Don't forget about the benefits of logging access. If the database is separated from the site, it can impose both access control and logging which someone compromising the site might not be able to destroy. It might be nice to at least have a record of what was compromised, and when...

Comment: okay, cool. Thanks for suggestions and discussion. So the hardware HSM is a way to go. Anyway, if someone doesnt' have spare 500 USD, is there any pure software analog of the same thing? Like I mentioned, having the specialized process doing encription for you seems feasible, but isn't it inventing a bycycle? Isn there any realiable software soluition for this?

Comment: or the reason can even be not the price. What if we are in virtualized server (or even shared hosting). There's no USB port to plug anything into.

Comment: A VM usually can access USB devices if they are made accessible. Shared hosting is a different kind of fish; you are more dependent on the security of the provider.

Comment: many provide openVZ virtualization with dozens of cheap VMs residing on the same server.it's unlikely it is possible to manage access to USB.

Comment: A software solution on the same computer is logically impossible.

Comment: Amazon has an HSM service. It's pretty expensive.

Comment: what about having a separate process doing all encryption/decryption for the app? It knows the key which is given to it at its startup. So the key is not stored in FS, the only place is that encryption "daemon"'s memory - not readable by anyone, unless the hack the OS kernel. Looks possible. What do you think?

Comment: @user1312695 depends if you need to protect the key if an attacker gets root

Comment: I dont think root can read the memory of another process. Or can it?

Comment: Root can do everything

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace Okay, then this idea is fundamentally wrong.